# How many ways to order $14$ books

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $5$ different history books, $7$ different physics books and $2$ different biology books means $14$ books in total.

How many different arrangements are possible if the books in each particular subject must all stand together? And only the physics books must stand together?

What I tried myself:

When all subjects must stand together, there are:

- $5!$ possibilities ($= 120$) to order the history books.
- $7!$ possibilities ($= 5040$) to order the physics books.
- $2$ possibilities to order the biology books.

Which means there are $5162$ possibilities to order the books.

And for only the physics books must stand together:

- $7!$ possibilities ($= 5040$) to order the physics books.
- $7!$ possibilities ($= 5040$) to order the other books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculations for the seperate subjects you made are correct, but you can't add them like that. For each of the $5040$ arrangements of physics books, each of the 2 arrangements of biology books can occur, so thats $5040\cdot2$. For all those arrangements, each of the $120$ arrangements of historybooks can occur. So thats $5040\cdot 2\cdot120$ in total. But now, the order of different groups of books has $3!=6$ possibilities, so in total, its $5040\cdot 2\cdot120\cdot 6$.

When only the physics books are together, there are $7!$ orderings for them. Now, assume this is just one 'book'. There are now $8=2+5+1$ books to place, so there are $8!$ orderings. In total, you get $7!\cdot 8!$.

Comment: With 5040 * 2 * 120 * 3 you mean 5040 * 2 * 120 * 6 i guess?

Comment: you're right, edited it

Answer (score 4):

But you can also vary the order in which the groups of books stand together, so in the first case, you can permute the *groups* of books in $3!$ ways, so you need to multiply (rule of the product) $$(5!\times 7! \times 2 )\times 3! = 7257600$$ possibilities to order the books (say, on a shelf).

And in the second case, you can choose any one of eight spots to place the 7 physics book. That is we can take the 7 physics books and bundle them together as "one" with the seven remaining books as single books, and they can be arranged on the shelf in $X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X$ ways, the bundle occupying any one of $8$ spots.. So we need to multiply your total by $8$: $$7! \times 7! \times 8 = 7!\times 8!$$

Comment: So in the first case it would be 3! * 5162, I get that.. but in the second case, where did 8! came from?

Comment: Ah I get it! 7 other books, and 1 for the subject of physics books. Thanks!

Comment: it should be $7!\cdot 7!\cdot 8=7!\cdot 8!$. The number given here is larger then $14!$, so this is not possible

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Hello my dear friend!. why did you delete this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/229734/8581?

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV -> +1